# getting jquery load/get use the current require.js path

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

require.js allows to smartly redefine the "include path" so that you can decide to install your dependancies into arbitrary sub-directories, transparently for them.

Well, this is true for the recursive require() these might do, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for the jquery load/get they might do: these still refere to html path, so that datas cannot be moved together with their lib.js.

- how to make  jquery load/get refer to this current require path ?
- or am I missusing require.js features ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `toUrl` for this. (Documented: go [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulenotes) in the documentation and search for `toUrl`.)

You need to have `require` as a dependency of your module (`define(["require", ...], function (require, ...) {...`) and then you call `require.toUrl(path)` where `path` is a path *relative to your module*. This call will return a path which is the same as if the `path` argument were a module's path defined in your RequireJS configuration. In other words, it is a path which will be relative if your `baseUrl` in your configuration was relative, or absolute if `baseUrl` is absolute. At any rate, you should just be able to feed it to `$().load` or `$.get`.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for the hint ! In my case, many js files are third party, not organised in modules, and some time with data (icons, css of elements). I prefer to have all of them in a lib or js directory rather than at the root level, and to transparently call them using require rather than including tons of them in the html file from <script>. -> is it good practice to assemble in a module third party js files that are not yours ?